# Metadata file does not contain valid metadata - Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, facebook-unity-sdk

I don't know what's going on here. I was able to create an APK for Android. So, it should be easy to make it a Facebook/WebGL game too, right? Apparently not. And, worse: even if I try to make a stand alone or Android build, I get the same error now.

```
 error CS0009: Metadata file `C:\...\Library/FacebookSDK/CanvasJSSDKBindings.jslib' does not contain valid metadata
```

I don't know what to do with this. I tried deleting it and letting it rebuild. I tried deleting everything in the project (except assets) and let all of that rebuild. I'm using Facebook SDK version 7.12.2. I'm using Unity 2017.3.1f1. Anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

This answer was taken verbatim from [the Unity forums](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1518861/metadata-file-does-not-contain-metadata.html).

---

Deleting folder [game path]\Library\FacebookSDK works for me.
You need to verify there is not a file named CanvasJSSDKBindings.jslib in this location.

You must have the following files inside the folder:

- Facebook.Unity.dll
- Facebook.Unity.Gameroom.dll
- Facebook.Unity.Settings.dll
- FacebookNamedPipeClient.dll
- ivy.xml
- version.txt

The contents of ivy.xml must be:

```
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ivy-module version="2.0" xmlns:e="http://ant.apache.org/ivy/extra">
   <info organisation="Facebook" module="FacebookSDK" e:packageType="UnityExtension">
     <description>Facebook SDK</description>
   </info>
   <publications>
      <artifact name="Facebook.Unity" type="dll" ext="dll" e:guid="2403d1f95ea54028853403e595bc9274" />
      <artifact name="Facebook.Unity.Gameroom" type="dll" ext="dll" e:guid="063ad293d9fe40e18bde10bbc71df334" />
      <artifact name="Facebook.Unity.Settings" type="dll" ext="dll" e:guid="18b4dbf8a0b54ea4adf46fb7f4d71dd0" />
      <artifact name="FacebookNamedPipeClient" type="dll" ext="dll" e:guid="51288a4fc4384861a5b1f9dd49b3da26" />
   </publications>
</ivy-module>`
```

I'm using Unity 2018.1.6f1 and Facebook SDK 7.13.0.